# pymongo.errors.OperationFailure saying ns does not exist

Tags: mapreduce

I got an error as following :
Traceback (most recent call last):

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('mapreduce',
>   u'tweets'),     ('map', Code('function() { emit(this.via, 1); }',
>   {})),    ('reduce', Code(' function(key,value) {\n       var res =
>   0;\n       values.forEach(function(v) {res += 1 })\n       return
>   {count: res};\n    }\n    ', {})), ('out', 'via_count')]) on namespace
>   Corpus.$cmd failed: ns doesn't exist

The codes are :

```
   from pymongo import MongoClient
   from bson.code import Code
   con = MongoClient()
   db     = con.Corpus
   tweets = db.tweets
   map    = Code("function() { emit(this.via, 1); }")
   reduce = Code(""" function(key,value) {
       var res = 0;
       values.forEach(function(v) {res += 1 })
       return {count: res};
    }
    """)

    result = tweets.map_reduce(map, reduce, "via_count")
    for doc in db.via_count.find():
        print(doc)
```

Comment: Any update on this? I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 4):

on namespace Corpus.$cmd failed: ns doesn't exist

It means you don't have collection named 'tweets' or 'via_count' in Corpus.

Not like a raw query in mongodb, map_reduce function doesn't make a new collection if it's not exist.

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.

Answer (score -2):

Even if the database does not exists drops the same error

Comment: Does this answer the question, or is it a comment/separate question?

Comment: It was a comment, an enhancement of the answer.